# Tab Bar Item doesn't work on storyboard in order to call another View

Tags: iphone, ios, xcode

Tab Bar Item doesn't work on storyboard in order to call another View

I press ctrl + drag to the view, waiting the same behavior than a regular button (showing the options to select modal call)

any directions?